# Generic makefile that is independent of source file name

Tags: c, makefile

I wanted to create a generic makefile that can take the source file name compile it, save it as the object file and executable file.  Both files using the original source name. Thank you for your help.

```
     exec: \

     compile
     ./helloworld  #I would like to input source outside the make file.




    compile: \

    helloworld.c 

    gcc -Wall helloworld.c -o helloworld #<==

    echo 'compiling'             
    touch compile


#I would like makefile to automatically save both object and exec. 
#as the source file name.
```

Comment: This is not the purpose of the Makefile, this is called a shell script.

Comment: So if you write `tomorrow.c`, and you invoke `make tomorrow`, you want Make to build `tomorrow.o` and `tomorrow` and then run `tomorrow`, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I will take a look  at the $bash option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` variable thus:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall

$(MAKECMDGOALS): $(MAKECMDGOALS).o
```

and then simply call Make like this:

```
make myfile
```

If you have Make 3.81 or later, then this can become:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall

.SECONDARY:  # Prevents intermediate files from being deleted
```

If you're not interested in saving the intermediate object file, then you don't even need a Makefile.  You can simply do:

```
make bar CFLAGS=-Wall
```

Comment: @agape: `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` takes on whatever you give Make as its target.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make has built-in rules that know how to create an executable from a source file, if they have the same name.  So you don't even need a makefile at all!

```
$ ls
foobar.c

$ make foobar
cc foobar.c -o foobar
```

Not that there's no need to mess with .SECONDARY because make has a direct rule to build an executable from a .c, without compiling the .o first (so there's no intermediate file).  Even if it didn't, there's no advantage here to keeping the .o file around so it's not worth the extra effort to do so (IMO).

If you want to change compilers or flags you can have a makefile that consists of nothing other than some variable assignments:

```
$ ls
foobar.c        Makefile

$ cat Makefile
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall

$ make foobar
gcc -Wall foobar.c -o foobar
```

Comment: i created the makefile and type in CC = gcc and CFLAGS = -Walll.  but it is not compiling my test.c file.   I will try to insert this in my previous makefile.

Comment: If you have `test.c` you are running `make test`, right?  It will definitely work.  BTW, calling your program "test" is generally a bad idea: there's a shell built-in named "test" so when you try to run your program you will be confused unless you give a path, such as `./test`.